# Input group with both group-btn and group-addon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use an input group with a button and then an addon with a tooltip info over a glyphicon. I have attached an image of how the end result looks like. You can see that the input field and button and addon are not in the same (visual) group.

Is there a way this can be done or should I opt for another solution?

This is the markup which produces result as seen in the image:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="Employer_EmployerTitle">Employer</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="Employer.EmployerTitle" class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="Employer_EmployerTitle" aria-invalid="false" style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" value="StackOverflow inc.">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnModalSearch" onclick="EmployerSearchModalShow()" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="toolTipSpanEmployerSearch" data-original-title="Search Employers from local database." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Employer.EmployerTitle"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="Employer_EmployerTitle">Employer</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="Employer.EmployerTitle" class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="Employer_EmployerTitle" aria-invalid="false" style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" value="StackOverflow inc.">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnModalSearch" onclick="EmployerSearchModalShow()" type="button">Search</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          <span title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="toolTipSpanEmployerSearch" data-original-title="Search Employers from local database." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Employer.EmployerTitle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pmzn3zs9/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I have tried this and it is working as expected. The gylphicon button is narrower compared to class="input-group-addon" but that can be fixed.